# Can someone identify this weed?

Tags: identification, weeds, annuals

It has been sprouting all over my garden and seems extremely hard to kill. I've been trying to look up information on it but nobody in the area seems to know the name, even though it seems to be growing all over Israel.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like 'bur ragweed', *Ambrosia confertiflora* to me.  However, you need the inflorescence (or sometimes the fruit) to ID the *Ambrosia* genera. It does not really matter as you deal with most of the genera the same way.  These are considered weeds in Israel. http://www.sviva.gov.il/InfoServices/ReservoirInfo/DocLib2/Publications/P0701-P0800/P0707.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that's the one. Unfortunately the pdf you linked basically says nothing helps with getting rid of them. Do you know of a way?

Comment: That's another question - and from what I gather you are supposed to ask just one here (but I see lots with more than one).  That pub does have control methods, maybe you didn't wait for it to load.  It's under "Control Methods". I don't have this as a weed for me, I only have the annuals, which I simply pull up.  I assume that for this one any perennial weed fix would work.  The chemicals mentioned especially glyphosate would probably work if applied at the end of the warm season as the plants go dormant later this month...

Comment: For similar plants here:  I use glyphosate. Don't over-apply and even under apply a little (mix at a slightly lower rate, and spray on twice, on two consecutive days).  Use a surfactant too (called spreader sticker here) to make it go into the plant.  These will allow the chemicals to go into the roots. Re-apply to any shoots that come up (you can use a rubber glove and a sponge to apply just to the plant). Or just cut off at the ground any sprouts.  If you keep this up they will eventually go away (hopefully).  Plant a thickly growing plant in place of it.  These plants don't like shade.

Comment: Don't know what agencies you have in Israel, but here we have the 'Extension Service' (an outgrowth of land-grant universities - to spread the knowledge of research to the public).  Maybe you have similar agencies there to contact...